# My $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post() return boolean (false)

Tags: ajax, yii2

can anyone tell why my `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()` return boolean (false) ? I try var_dump the `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()` and it certainly has my input value (not null).

Here's my code. I'm working on an editable input field based on `Vitalet's x-editable`.  This field will modify the value of `tema` column of the database (`tema` 's model attribute). I try to `print_r($model->getErrors())` in the 'else' statement and I got
 
`Array
(
)`

```
public function actionFetch(){
//There's only a single row in the table.
$model= Home::find()->one();

if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

// use Yii's response format to encode output as JSON
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

// save posted model attributes
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

//extract the class name
$modelClassName = \yii\helpers\StringHelper::basename(get_class($model));
//grab the post parameters array (as attribute=>value)
$params = Yii::$app->request->post($modelClassName);
//pull the first value from the array (there should only be one) 
$value = reset($params);

// return JSON encoded output in the below format
return ['output'=>$value, 'message'=>'success'];

} else {
// else if nothing to do always return an empty JSON encoded output
// alternatively you can return a validation error
return ['output'=>'', 'message'=>'fail'];
}
};


}
```

The view :

```
<a href="#" id="tema" name="tema" data-type="text" data-pk=<?=$model->id?> data-url=<?=Url::to(['home/fetch']);?> data-title="Enter username"><?=$model->tema?></a>
```

My model's rule :

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [[ 'id','isiTema', 'image', 'midLeft_title', 'midLeft_content', 'midCenter_title', 'midCenter_content', 'midRight_title', 'midRight_content', 'footerLeft', 'footerRight', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'required'],
            [['midLeft_content', 'midCenter_content', 'midRight_content', 'footerLeft', 'footerRight'], 'string'],
            [['id'],'integer'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
            [['tema', 'isiTema', 'image', 'midLeft_title', 'midCenter_title', 'midRight_title'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }
```

This is my `var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post())` contains :

```
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "tema"
  ["value"]=>
  string(5) "aaabb"
  ["pk"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

I try this in my controller but still the result is the same (basically I think I don't need to as it only contains a single row in the table) :

```
...
 $pk = $_POST['pk'];

$model=Home::find()->where(['id'=>$pk])->one();
...
...
```

Comment: add content of What `Yii::$app->request->post()` contains.

Comment: are yiu sure that  you post and model match??

Comment: @InsaneSkull  I have updated it. Please check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @scaisEdge Sorry I don't really get it, how to check? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `load()` with second argument set to `''` to explicitly state that your POST fields are not including model name.

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got this warning that has something to do with my `reset()` method :
`{name: "PHP Warning", message: "reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given", code: 2,…}`

Comment: That means my answer is proper and you are finally inside that condition block but obviously there is no POST param you are looking for there so `$params` is null.

Comment: you're right, the `$params` is null. It seems that the model fail to populate the data using the `load()` method. I try to var_dump the `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()` again and it returns `bool(false)`. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Updated : I try `var_dump($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(),''))` and now it's true. But still why could the `params` is null? The `modelClassName` is fine, though. And the `var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post())` also contains something (additional information had been added in my first post)

Comment: You are not sending parameters required by your own rules. You don't need `load()`, just take `Yii::$app->request->post('value')`, check if it's valid, set `$model->tema` with it and save `$model`... smh

Comment: I try to do as you say and it works. `if(isset($_POST)){
$model->tema=$value;
$model->save();
return ['output'=>$value, 'message'=>'success'];
}`
Do you have any idea how to pass the parameters if I need the params? So that it can automatically knew which attribute should be populated with the input value. The solution above works only if I have one editable field in my view, in the case above, I could 'hard-code' $model->tema into the value. But if I have more than one editable field, it won't work

Comment: Solved. I just passed the `name` parameter and then made it like `$model->$name=$value`. Though I don't know if it's a good practice. Thanks !